# Is there any method that can get solution more accurate than integral3 by MATLAB (except using "for" loop)?

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to calculate the torque an ellipsoid gets in a gravity field. In theory, the torque the ellipsoid gets should become zero as `alpha` goes to zero.  However, MATLAB returned a nonzero value for the following integral:

```
e = 1/1737100/10^2;
D = 384399000;
G = 6.6743*10^(-11);
R = 1737100;
M = 5.97237*10^24;
alpha = 0;

dT = @(r,theta,phi) ((1+e).*sin(theta).*sin(phi).*sin(alpha)+cos(theta).*cos(alpha)).*r.^3.*sin(theta)./(r.^2+D.^2-2.*r.*D.*((1+e).*sin(theta).*sin(phi).*cos(alpha)-cos(theta)*sin(alpha))).^(3./2);
Torque = G.*M.*D.*(1+e).*integral3(dT,0,R,0,pi,0,2*pi)
```

I guess this is because that `integral3` just inputs a matrix into the equation to get the numerical solution.  So I am wondering, is there any numerical method which we can use to get a more accurate solution than `integral3`?  Ideally computational time shouldn't be too high and of course, if an analytical solution exists, I'd be happy to hear about that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You have posted a whole lot of code, of which especially the first block looks like it's unrelated to the problem (lots of plotting, recalculations and video writing). See [mcve], the more minimal, i.e. smaller, your example code, the more likely people are to help you. The second block runs stand alone and is all that's necessary to answer your question, so I suggest that you [edit] the question to remove the first code block.

Comment: Numerical precision is always an issue in high-precision computing. You can try to use [Variable-Precision Arithmetic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) to boost that, although it will cost you dearly in performance speed.